# MS Access Group by query by n records

Tags: ms-access-2010

Does anybody know how to do a group by query by n records.

For example if I have a db with `xn` records  I would like to aggregate the first 3 and then the next 3 and so on.

Where {x,n member of positive integers excluding 0} :)

Thanks

Comment: It might be possible, but you need to post your table structure along with a data sample

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you want :

```
SELECT int(((T.Rank - 1) / 3)) AS GroupID, SUM(T.field_to_agregate) 
FROM
(
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table AS T2 WHERE T1.ID>T2.ID) + 1 AS Rank , ID, field_to_agregate
FROM your_table AS T1
) T

GROUP BY int(((T.Rank - 1) / 3))
```

However since you did not posted any data sample and table structure (mistake!), I had to suppose that you have an ID field in your table, if not you will have to adapt it. If you don't suceed add more info about your data and I will adapt my query to match your table struct